# Combining 2 Aggregates using Merge in R

Tags: r, merge

Here I am getting an "undefined columns selected" error.  Full disclosure: I am relatively new to R.

What I need to do is split out the serial into 2 parts, >6 & =6 characters.

Here is an example of it working in Excel:

```
Child Serial    Cost
N1647961       64.58
```

Formula:  `=SUMIF(B:B,G98,D:D)+SUMIF(B:B,LEFT(G98,6),D:D)`

I created a list of unique child serials to run this formula on.

Where `B:B` is the vanilla `serial number`, `G98` is the child serial, `column D` is the `cost`.  So first it sums the child costs for the serials that match, then it takes the left 6 digits of that child serial, and sums the relevant parent costs.  Then you end up with all the costs to produce that child.

">6" are the "child serials", then the "=6" are the "parent serials", thus a parent can have many children.  A "child" is distinguished by the characters after the initial 6. so "123456" is the parent, "789" is the child.

```
df1 <- subset(dBase, nchar(dBase$Serial) = 6)
df2 <- subset(dBase, nchar(dBase$Serial) > 6)
```

Here I am aggregating the costs per Parent & Child serial in each df1a/b

```
df1a <- aggregate(df1$process_cost,
                list(serial1 = df1$Serial),
                FUN = sum)

df2a <- aggregate(df2$process_cost,
                list(serial2 = df2$Serial),
                FUN = sum)
```

Works up to this point.

Here is where I'm trying to "merge" those costs into df2a, so I can have all the costs incurred for the parent, then have all the costs for the child, then add them together and get total cost so costs are shown per parent-child pair.  Then my plan was to merge this df3 back into the main df (or dBase, just using df for this example) and line up the costs to show in the main file.

**Problem** Here I am getting an "undefined columns selected" error.  Am I making this entirely too difficult ?

```
df3 <- merge(df2a,
             df1a[,c(df1a$serial1, df1a$x)],
             by = substr(df2a$serial2,1, 6))
```

**Sample:**  Here you want to be able to disect the parents e.g. 123456 and match it with the costs of the child, here it's 10 so you'd get a total cost of 11, then for 987654 you'd get 22 and so on.  A parent, can have multiple children so "123456-789" "123456-333", "123456-114" and so on.  (added dashes for a clearer example).

```
serial <- c('123456','987654', '000001', '000002', '123456789', '987654321', '000001234', '000002345')
costs  <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30, 40)

df <- data.frame(serial, costs)

     serial costs
1    123456     1
2    987654     2
3    000001     3
4    000002     4
5 123456789    10
6 987654321    20
7 000001234    30
8 000002345    40
```

Comment: Sorry about that, just added an example, it's "=" to 6 are the parents and ">6" are the childs, sorry about that.

Comment: I am just a wizard of confusion, aren't I ? Ha!  Yes I just changed everything to "df" for this SO post.  The "123456" & child of "789" was just used for the sample.  The actual serials are a mix of characters ("e.g. D12945").  Could this be a data type issue?  The serial, typeof = character

Comment: Thx for the edits! character is no prob. The by clause is the prob, it may only contain column names, not expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the output you want.

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, parent := substr(serial, 1, 6)]
df[, child  := substr(serial, 7, 1000000000)]
df[, total_cost := sum(costs), by = parent]
```

The first step is to create a column `parent` that will have a unique value for each parent. The second step creates a `child` column, which may not be necessary for what you want to do. The final step sums all of the costs by `parent`.

Result:

```
#       serial costs parent child total_cost
# 1:    123456     1 123456               11
# 2:    987654     2 987654               22
# 3:    000001     3 000001               33
# 4:    000002     4 000002               44
# 5: 123456789    10 123456   789         11
# 6: 987654321    20 987654   321         22
# 7: 000001234    30 000001   234         33
# 8: 000002345    40 000002   345         44
```

If you want the unique cost for each parent, use `unique(df[, .(parent, total_cost)])`.

```
#    parent total_cost
# 1: 123456         11
# 2: 987654         22
# 3: 000001         33
# 4: 000002         44
```

Comment: Slight issue, the total_cost is showing all the same value, which I think it's summing the entire df instead of per parent.  So when I do unique(df$total_cost), it shows just 1 value.

Comment: Trying to figure out why it works in the example but not in the actual df

Answer (score 1):

So there are a bunch of problems with the code above, but the reason you get the `undefined columns` error is because `R` doesn't understand what `df1a[,c(df1a$serial1, df1a$x)]` is (when you're merging the two dfs). Instead you can use `df1a[,c("serial1", "x")]`. That will solve this particular error, but the code won't work because there's more problems (in particular with the `by` argument).

Overall to get what you want I'd suggest using the `by` argument in `aggregate`.

```
 > aggregate(costs~substr(df$serial,1, 6), sum, data=df)
  substr(df$serial, 1, 6) costs
1                  000001    33
2                  000002    44
3                  123456    11
4                  987654    22
```

There are way too many ways to do this in `R` and most of them are more efficient (like `data.table` or `group_by` and `mutate` in `dplyr`), but since you asked about `aggregate`, I'm sticking with it.

Comment: @RYoda you're absolutely right! I totally missed it, I'm updating the code to get what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thx for fixing the solution - definitely the shortest solution (1-liner :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I didn't write a good enough description.  A parent can have multiple children.  So "123456" parent can go into "123456-789" "123456-333", "123456-114", etc...

Comment: @AspiringDeveloper it still works, given that `substr(df$serial,1, 6)` will pick all observations that start with each 6-digit serial number. So if parent `123456` has 2 kids, e.g. `123456-789` and `123456-333`, and their costs are `1, 10, 60`, then the above code will give you `71` on the costs column. Or do you want a total cost per parent-child pair?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  Total costs per parent-child pair.

Answer (score 0):

Using just a `data.frame` (not a `data.table` - you can already find an answer by @EricWatt):

```
df$group <- substr(df$serial, 1, 6)
aggregate(costs ~ group, df, sum)
```

results in

```
  group costs
1 000001    33
2 000002    44
3 123456    11
4 987654    22
```

To make it all reproducible the required code parts of your question:

```
serial <- c('123456','987654', '000001', '000002', '123456789', '987654321', '000001234', '000002345')
costs  <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30, 40)
df <- data.frame(serial, costs, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the total costs per parent-child pair?  So if parent A12345 has children A12345-111, '... -112', '...-113' and so on?  If I can explain the goal another way, it's to track all the costs that went into making that child.

Comment: To group by multiple data.frame columns use: `res <- aggregate(costs ~ group + serial, df, sum)`. You then have to filter out only the parent-only rows with `res[res$group != res$serial,]`